# could not post to asp.net core web api using windows authentication

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

The api is AspNetCore WebApi with default configuration for Windows authentication and CORS enabled. The client is Angular with GET and POST methods.

The GET call is successful:

```
this.http.get("https://localhost:44358/api/values", {withCredentials:true})
  .subscribe(a=> {
    console.log(a);
    this.list=a;        
  });
```

The POST is failed:

```
this.http.post("https://localhost:44358/api/values", {value:"aaa"}, {withCredentials:true})
  .subscribe(a=> {
    console.log(a);
    this.list=a;        
  });
```

02 exceptions are

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:44358/api/values 401 (Unauthorized)
```

and

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44358/api/values' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any idea please?

Comment: This is problem with CORS not with Angular. Error is clear, you need to implement "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the backend side. Reason of CORS in your case is different ports of apps (client and server). PS. Make sure you allow OPTIONS request, it is necessary to make CORS works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST causes the browser to send OPTIONS to the web api before real POST. However the webapi rejects this call because the configuration is based on Windows authentication only. The solution is to enable both Windows authentication for controllers as well as anonymous authentication for OPTIONS in `launchSetting.json`.

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true, 
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
```

and add 1 line before `AddMvc` in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: what if I don't want to enable anonymousAuthentication? Isn't there another way?